# duplicate boolean value in swagger ui

Tags: rest, spring-boot, swagger-ui

I have created a Rest API endpoint to create an employee with isAvailable Boolean type as a property of bean class.
But in swagger UI it shows duplicate, one available and another one isAvailable.
That is very weird, below is the sample.

```
{
  available: true,
  "address": {
    "city": "string",
    "country": "string",
    "id": 0,
    "postalCode": "string",
    "street": "string"
  },
  "employeeId": 0,
  "employeeEmail": "string",
  "firstname": "string",
  "lastname": "string",
  "telephone": "string",
  "isAvailable": true
}
```

I searched on swagger docs but did not find any clue nor in any blog post. I must not be the first one to encounter this problem.
How to solve this problem?

Comment: Please post your source code (with annotations) for that class, and your Swagger/Springfox config.

Comment: @Helen No annotation, The POJO class has boolean member variable with name isAvailable. Thats it. And basing setting for swagger just docket config.

Comment: I have same situation here. From what I see, the Swagger UI it works ok if I change from primitive boolean type to composed Boolean type.

Answer (score 3):

Swagger strips the "is" if a variable is a boolean.
Can be fixed by annotating the getter:

```
@JsonGetter("isAvailable")
public boolean isAvailable() {
    return isAvailable;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Lombok, this turns a bit tricky as @JsonGetter is not allowed on variables. In that case use below

```
@JsonProperty("is_available")
private boolean available;
```